# Create a simple two cell/column table in Latex with some rows that span both cells (for title)

Tags: tables

Im struggling with creating tables in LateX. I want to create a pretty simple table, I think but I don't know how to go about.

I have included an image of what I am trying to get at. This is just a generalized example. I have some more Areas and the subareas for the different areas also vary (some have e.g. only 2 and others have 7, I think)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

With `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTableCommand\SCB{\SetCell[c=2]{l, font=\bfseries}}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec  = {X[l]X[l]},
                }
\SCB    Area x  &       \\
subarea x       &       \\
subarea x       &       \\
subarea x       &       \\
\SCB    Area y  &       \\
subarea y       &       \\
subarea y       &       \\
\SCB    Area z  &       \\
subarea z       &       \\
subarea z       &       \\
subarea z       &       \\
subarea z       &       \\
subarea z       &       \\
subarea z       &       \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**
You should make yourself more familiar with writing table with LaTeX. For star, reading some introductory text abot this, for example as is
[wiki/LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). Beside `tabularray` package -- relative new and very powerful package for writing of tables -- exist other packages too: for example `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{m}{\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
\mcl{Area x}            \\
    \hline
subarea x       &       \\
    \hline
subarea x       &       \\
    \hline
subarea x       &       \\
    \hline
\mcl{Area y}            \\
    \hline
subarea y       &       \\
    \hline
subarea y       &       \\
    \hline
\mcl{Area z}            \\
    \hline
subarea z       &       \\
    \hline
subarea z       &       \\
    \hline
subarea z       &       \\
    \hline
subarea z       &       \\
    \hline
subarea z       &       \\
    \hline
subarea z       &       \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Result of compilation is very similar as before.

Comment: I get the error: File "tabularray.sty" not found when I try to run this, so I think maybe its not a part of my environment. For my other tables I have used \usepackage[table]{xcolor} and \usepackage{booktabs}. I don't know if it is easier to make a solution within those packages, or get the tabularray package

Comment: I have any information where and how you test my solution. From error follows, that you not have installed this package. Install it!